# Select field unless another field contains duplicate

Tags: sql

I've created sample data representing what I have below (actual database has about 30 fields per record and 60k records in this table)

| Customer_ID | CaseType | CaseStatus | DateOpened | DateClosed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Letter | Letter | 01/01/2023 | 01/03/2023 |
| 100 | Call | Call | 01/02/2023 | 01/04/2023 |
| 200 | Letter | Letter | 01/01/2023 | 01/03/2023 |

As an example, I need to return all "*Customer_ID*" that have:

- "*CaseType = Letter*"
- "*DateClosed = 01/03/2023*"
  unless there is a matching "*Customer_ID*" that has a "*CaseType = Call*", regardless of any other fields.

So basically from the above I would end with only one record, that being "*Customer_ID = 200*" as it has "*CaseStatus='Letter'*" without a matching call, and it was closed on 01/03/2023.

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer_ID 
WHERE CaseType = 'Letter' AND DateClosed = '01/03/2023'
```

which obvioulsy returns me both 100 and 200, but I cant figure out the "unless matching Customer_ID and CaseType = Call" part. I'm assuming it may involves the `IF` command, or `NOT IF` if that even exists.

Any pointers / assistance would be gratefully received.

Comment: Your SELECT needs a FROM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way with a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Customer_ID

FROM TABLE

WHERE CaseType = 'Letter'
    AND DateClosed = '01/03/2023'
    AND Customer_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT
             Customer_ID
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE CaseType = 'Call'
    )
```

This way you are excluding all `Customer_ID` with a `CaseType = 'Call'`.

In SQL the `IF` and `NOT IF` can be thought in the `WHERE` statement.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked with some minor editing. I hadnt noticed there was more than just Call and Letter (there was email and a few others).  So I changed the last = ‘Call’ to != “Letter”.  Seems strange having a NOT IN and Not Equal in the same sub but it seems to have worked!   Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, yes, that works too! Using a subquery is not efficient on a large database but for your table will do the job and it's easy to understand. If you're satisfied you can mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `NOT EXISTS` operator, assuming your DBMS supports it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Customer_ID  
FROM tab t1
WHERE t1.CaseType = 'Letter' AND t1.DateClosed = '01/03/2023'
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tab t2 WHERE t2.CaseType = 'Call'
                                        AND t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID)
```